# Echelon form of a matrix over the integers using maple

Tags: linear-algebra, maple

I need to find the (row) echolon form **over the integers** $\mathbb{Z}$, using maple. I know how to do this over $\mathbb{Q}$, using 'ReducedRowEchelonForm' of the package 'LinearAlgebra'.

I also know how to reduce a matrix to the echelon form, over the integers, using **sage**; but it would be much more comfortable to use one coding system for my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `HermitForm` from the `MatrixPolynomialAlgebra` package.

---

Example:

```
A:= <<0,-1,-2,1>|<-3,-3,-3,4>|<-6,-1,0,5>|<9,1,-1,-7>>;

LinearAlgebra:-ReducedRowEchelonForm(A);
```

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0& 0& 1/2\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&-3/2\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

```
MatrixPolynomialAlgebra:-HermiteForm(A);
```

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&-1\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&2&-3\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$